# Can "arrovellarsi" be used as a stronger version of "chiedersi"?

Tags: difference

> **Mi arrovello**... Il cibo di questo treno sarà commestibile?
>
> **Mi chiedo davvero**... Il cibo di questo treno sarà commestibile?

I wonder if "mi arrovello" can be used like "mi chiedo davvero"? Or does "arrovellarsi" mean something slightly different than that?

The descriptions [here](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/arrovellarsi) do not seem to correspond exactly to the usage of this "mi arrovello".

Comment: I am glad that you resorted to a monolingual dictionary, Alone-zee. Since it already gave you the solution, do you want to try and write an answer yourself?

Comment: Not up to the task, I'm afraid!

Comment: In any case, you found the correct answer yourself!

Answer (score 2):

I think that in your case "mi arrovello" doesn't mean "mi chiedo davvero".

Treccani gives these definitions for [arrovellare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/arrovellare/):

> 1. ant. Infastidire (to annoy), tormentare (to harass, to torment). Nowadays only in the figurative phrase  "arrovellarsi il cervello", to go about finding a solution for something.
> 2. refl. a. Rodersi internamente (to be internally eaten), arrabbiarsi (to become irritated), stizzirsi (to get angry): "non arrovellarti per queste sciocchezze", don't distress yourself on these foolishnesses.
>
>     b. Affannarsi (to wary, to strive relentlessly to achieve a goal): si arrovella per vivere; si arrovellava
>    inutilmente a convincerlo; si è arrovellato tutto il pomeriggio su un
>    problema di matematica.

In your case I would use "mi domando" instead of "mi arrovello".